# Lossless JPG rotation as a Nautilus context menu or lightweight GUI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, image-processing

I often have to rotate JPG pictures that are precious originals, often taken years ago with cameras that did not have many pixels. Right now I rotate them with GIMP, but due to the arbitrary compression rate that results in quality loss or bigger pictures, both of which I want to avoid. And also GIMP is very slow to start.

So, I am looking for a tool that can rotate pictures:

- without JPG quality loss (each 8x8 square compressed the same)
- without significant size increase
- easily accessible from the Nautilus file manager

  - ideally in the right-click context menu ("Rotate 45° clockwise", "Rotate 45° counter-clockwise", "Rotate 180°")
  - or as a fast tool that can be launched from the Nautilus context menu, and allows me to rotate the image in less than 5 seconds after I click to launch it.
- Preserves EXIF information
- Gratis, ideally open source
- Runs on Linux

For images whose height or width is not a multiple of 8, adding a few black pixels lines to make the squares match is OK.